# How to find PHANDLE of a process in a windows kernel mode driver?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-kernel, windows-driver

So basically, I am trying to create a kernel mode driver and there is no proper documentation so I just want to terminate a process, but that needs a PHANDLE and the only way I know to get a PHANDLE is to use the OpenProcess() function but, you cant do that while creating a kernel mode driver because you need to include windows.h and that just gives out a lot of errors anyone have any idea how to get this PHANDLE thing?

I tried using OpenProcess() function but it involves including windows.h which gives a lot of errors.

Sorry if this question is a little stupid because I am very new to stackoverflow.

Comment: [`NtOpenProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/nf-ntddk-ntopenprocess).

Comment: That returns an NTSTATUS which isn't what I need, I need a PHANDLE.

Comment: The return value informs you whether the operation succeeded. The handle is returned through the `ProcessHandle` parameter. All of this is explained in the documentation.

Comment: What do you mean I dont understand, I need the PHANDLE variable which I don't have to terminate a process and I am asking how to get that, the NtOpenProcess() function doesn't return a PHANDLE, and it actually requires a PHANDLE

Comment: A `PHANDLE` is a type alias for a `HANDLE*`. You create a variable of type `HANDLE`, assign a value of 0 to it, and pass its address into `NtOpenProcess` (or `ZwOpenProcess`). Upon successful execution of the call, the variable now holds a valid `HANDLE` value that refers to the process.

Comment: *That returns an NTSTATUS which isn't what I need, I need a PHANDLE.* - not sure that you need write driver at this stage